# NodaTime: Instant to ZonedDateTime without skewing time

Tags: c#, datetime, nodatime

I have a date time that is stored in our backend systems like `2019-11-27T00:00:00`.
I now want to use that data, that represent the date and time regardless of the timezone, as a part of a JSON document that is shipped to external users.

I'm currently using the Noda Time type `Instant` to represent the above values.

```
InstantPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss").Parse("2019-11-27T00:00:00").Value;
```

When I later want to output the time in the JSON document I would like to convert it to a type that also can represent the time zone for the current object. The time zones are known.

As an example, the above value should be represented like this in the document:
**Sweden**: `2019-11-27T00:00:00+01:00`
**Finland**: `2019-11-27T00:00:00+02:00`

The reason I want to do this is that the date and time in the database represents the time that an event occurs in local time for the current data consumer. An example would be a "Black Friday" sale that starts midnight of the actual country the sale is in, not when midnight occurs in UTC or likewise. By setting the time zone information in the output JSON I can guarantee that the consumers of the data get the correct information.

All my attempts to use the ZonedDateTime from an Instant, the Instant is treated as UTC time and the output becomes incorrect. There is probably something I'm missing, but I'm unfortunately stuck.

My questions are:

- is NodaTime the correct Library for this?
- is Instant the correct data type for the database values?
- is ZonedDateTime the correct way of working?
- how can I convert a Instant to any other type that can contain TimeZone information?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Just for clarity: `+01:00` is _not_ a "TimeZone". It is an Offset. Most of the time, this will be equivavalent, but it is _not_ the same, though. But on topic: If you want zoned Timestamps in the DB, why don't you store the zone (or offset) along with it?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the offset. I do not want the zoned data in database, as one object is valid in 10 countries. The time the object is valid start for example 2019-11-27T00:00:00. And this is different UTC times regarding the countries. In Sweden that is 2019-11-26T23:00:00Z and in Finland it's 2019-11-26T22:00:00Z

Comment: You can generate a DateTimeOffset using the [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid) method (since the time zones are known). JSON works well with `DateTimeOffset` objects. If the TimeZones are instead just offsets, you can use the DateTimeOffset methods to add it.

Comment: As a mother clarification from my side. The data is originating from a main frame ERP. The data in the ERP is valid globally, as we always say "This item can be sold from the midnight of November 27". And midnight November 27 occurs regarding to the country. So the store can not sell the item in Finland even if it can sell it Sweden or England.

Comment: ... but you want it to be 2019-11-27T00:00:00 local time for all countries, right? I think it should be enough to add the countries' offset. But I don't know how that works in Noda ...

Comment: Fildor, totalt correct. I have not found a way in either Microsofts APIs or NodaTimes APIs to do just that, add the offset information. So the best would be to just create a custom converter for the JSON document and add the offset to the output in your opinon?

Comment: Jimi: Thanks for your input. This gives me the output I want! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments above of some great people, I've solved my issue by

- Using Instant as the type from the database to keep other developers from mistaking it for a local date and time
- Converting the Instant to a DateTime and then applying `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId` just in time for creating the JSON output.